# Is is possible to generate object from ko.mapping.toJS to build Add / edit screen

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a pretty huge model which I need to bind with my view. and on UI I need to provide add / edit capability (using jquery model popup) .. I am using mapping plug-in to map my json data from server. And that's where thing gets tricky .. so what I am trying to achieve is whether It could be possible to create an object somehow -

var obj = ko.mapping.toJS(viewmodel)

I am using custom binding like this -

```
<div id="dailog" title="Employee .." class="dialog" data-bind="Dialog: { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, height: 'auto', width: 'auto', position: {my: 'center', at: 'center'} }, template: { name: 'editTmpl', data: DataService.selectedItem, if: DataService.selectedItem }, openDialog: DataService.selectedItem"> 
</div>
var mapping = {
    'EmpList': {
    create: function (options) {
    return new EmpMapping(options.data);
    }
};

var EmpMapping = function (data) {
      ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
        };

  var DataService = (function () {
  var mapping,
  viewModel, 
  selectedItem = ko.observable("");

  function editItem(context) { //this is working.
    selectedItem(context);
  }

  function AddNewItem(obj) {  // this is not working .. reason being I am not able to create new instance of a Employee. I was trying with ko.mapping.toJS 
       debugger
       var myObj = ko.toJS(viewModel.EmpList);
       var z = ko.mapping.fromJS({}, mapping, myObj);
       selectedItem(z);
   }

  return{
      editItem: editItem,
      saveItem: saveItem,
      init : init
      selectedItem : selectedItem
  }
}());
```

Comment: The code above is incomplete, I can't tell what the view model is in the first place.  Can you provide a jsfiddle or a complete listing of the code for the view model.  I don't need to see your custom binding, but I can't tell what viewModel.EmpList is or how selectedItem is being generated.

Comment: You write an object with the same properties as the server-side object (as observables), and add a constructor to that object. 
Your `EmpMapping` is a step in the right direction.